# Gulp project deploy to Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, gulp

I am trying to deploy Gulp project to Tomcat server when I release it and deploy to server the project can not load the resource 
Here is will find that the server Failed to find the files such as the css and js:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must configure the tomcat by specifying the path to ready resources after `gulp` building
[Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html)

```
  <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Or you can reconfigurate you gulp for current tomcat mapping